# DRY JS - How to Combine Identical JavaScript Functions into One?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I have a JS function that loads the same re-size function based on the button id.

**[JS Fidle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WayBehind/74oh88zu/)**

I'm trying to simplify the code to keep it DRY and clean. Since I can have 100+ of these buttons on a single page, I need to somehow make the code more dynamic.

```
var a = $('.a').popover();
a.on("show.bs.popover", function(e) {
    a.data()["bs.popover"].$tip.css("max-width", "630px");
});

var b = $('.b').popover();
b.on("show.bs.popover", function(e) {
    b.data()["bs.popover"].$tip.css("max-width", "630px");
});

var c = $('.c').popover();
c.on("show.bs.popover", function(e) {
    c.data()["bs.popover"].$tip.css("max-width", "630px");
});

var d = $('.d').popover();
d.on("show.bs.popover", function(e) {
    d.data()["bs.popover"].$tip.css("max-width", "630px");
});
```

I tried this but it only works for the first button:

```
var a = $('.a, .b, .c, .d,').popover();
a.on("show.bs.popover", function (e) {
    a.data()["bs.popover"].$tip.css("max-width", "630px");
});
```

Any ideas?

All I need is to make the bootstrap `Popover` window 600px.

Comment: try `$(this).data()["bs.popover"].$tip.css("max-width", "630px");`

Comment: Yes, this works inside the ajax load! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use this inside the closure so you reference the active element

```
$('.a, .b, .c, .d').popover().on("show.bs.popover", function (e) {
    $(this).data()["bs.popover"].$tip.css("max-width", "630px");
});
```

also weird on how you use data and not put the key inside. Normally you would use `data("key")` instead of the bracket notation

```
    $(this).data("bs.popover").$tip.css("max-width", "630px");
```

Comment: Thank you! Your first option is working. That being said, wondering if there is any better way so I dont have to load all the `ID` inside the JS

Comment: Edit. Both of your options are working the the second line inside the ajax `load` is eliminating the need for the ID list!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var a = $('.a, .b, .c, .d,');
a.each(function(){
  var $this = jQuery(this);
  $this.popover();
  $this.on("show.bs.popover", function (e) {
    $this.data("bs.popover").$tip.css("max-width", "630px");
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Unfortunately, this option is not working for me. Thanks again for the effort!